# How can i Change the of Color of main-div to green when upload was succees?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to upload a `csv`. What I want to do is when the upload succeeds change the color of the page (`main-div`) to green. When it fails, turn it red. I want to do it in same php script.

**Here is my code:**

```
<div id="main-div" class="content bg-gray-lighter">    
    <h3 class=" pull-right"><a href="<?php echo $one->assets_folder; ?>/download/sample_csv.csv"><span class="label label-warning"><i class="fa fa-download "></i> Download Sample Format Here <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o "></i> </span></a></h3>
    <?php
    include "../classes/connection.php"; //Connect to Database
    //Upload File
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        echo "<div id='main-div' class='block-content block-content-full bg-danger text-white-op'>";
        $deleterecords = "UPDATE TABLE data"; //empty the table of its current records
        mysql_query($deleterecords);
        $product = $_POST['product'];
        $courier = $_POST['courier'];
        $billmonth = $_POST['billmonth'];
        $billyear = $_POST['billyear'];
        $billrun = $_POST['billrun'];
        $dispatchtype = $_POST['dispatchtype'];
        $Received_Date=$_POST['Received_Date'];

        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
            echo "<p>Displaying contents:</p>";
            echo "<p>Product - <strong style='color: #ffc128'>".$product. " </strong> Service Provider - <strong style='color: #ffc128'>".$courier. "</strong> Bill Month - <strong style='color: #ffc128'>".$billmonth. " </strong> Bill Year - <strong style='color: #ffc128'>".$billyear. "</strong> Bill Run- <strong style='color: #ffc128'>" .$billrun. " </strong> Dispatch Type - <strong style='color: #ffc128'>".$dispatchtype."</strong></p><br/>";
            echo "<span style='color:#feffa4'>";
            readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
            echo "</span>";
        }

        //Import uploaded file to Database
        $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $linecount++ == count(file('filename.csv'));
            $data[2] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data[2]));
            $data[5] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data[5]));

            if (($product==$data[0]) && ($courier==$data[1]) && (strcasecmp($billmonth,$data[6])==0) && ($billyear==$data[7]) && ($billrun==$data[8]) && ($dispatchtype==$data[9])) {
                $import = "INSERT into data(Product,Courier,Received_Date,Acc_No,Received_By,Delivered_Date,Month,Year,Bill_Run,Dispatch_Type,Status,Bounce_Code) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]','$data[9]','$data[10]','$data[11]')";
            } else {
                /*echo "<div class='block-content block-content-full bg-city text-white-op'>";*/
                echo " <br/> <br/>Data Error.<br/>";
                echo "  <br/><br/><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary'><i class='si si-action-undo'></i> Go Back and Upload Again</a> <br/> <br/>";
            }

            mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
        }

        fclose($handle);
        ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#main-div').addClass('block-content block-content-full bg-success text-white-op');
</script>

        <?php
        /* echo "<div class='block-content block-content-full bg-success text-white-op'>";*/
        echo "<br/><br/><br/>";
        print "$linecount Records have been Imported ";
        echo "  <br/><br/><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary'><i class='si si-action-undo'></i> Go Back and Upload Again</a> <a href='index.php' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary'><i class='si si-home'></i> Home</a>  <br/> <br/>";
        //view upload form
        echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Just add a class to the div when upload is completed, and style them with green color

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
               $('#main-div').css('background','red'); // make red or green in your condition
            </script>

Comment: @sagar its not working

Comment: @Colombo, You mention color of page, do you want background color of page? or font color of page ?

Answer (score 0):

Put the code to change color to green inside the success if condition and red color in else condition as below

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
   /*Your code*/
   echo "<script>$('#main-div').css('background-color','green');</script>";
}
else {
  echo "<script>$('#main-div').css('background-color','red');</script>";
}
```

If it not work then try to add color on document ready as below

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
  /*Your code*/
  echo "<script>$(document).ready(function(){$('#main-div').css('background-color','green');});</script>";
}
else {
  echo "<script>$(document).ready(function(){$('#main-div').css('background-color','red');});</script>";
}
```

Comment: First try to create one sample demo using these options on your local server and then implement in actual code once demo work successfully. I have made it working on my local server.